# Greedy algorithm for 0-1 Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

Is there any greedy algorithm that would give an optimal solution to non-fractional(0-1 Knapsack) Knapsack problem? I know that there is one for the fractional version of Knapsack giving the optimal solution.

Comment: No there (probably) isn't. I say probably since there are infinitely many ways you can solve it greedily (consider that you can order by any possible function with 2 parameters (weight and cost)). The best greedy 0-1 knapsack algorithm I know of would guarantee to get you within 50% of the optimal. If they're all the same weight or all the same value, then greedy will give the optimal.

Comment: @Dukeling: could you please give a link or describe the greedy algorithm you mentioned (which guarantees 50% optimality)?

Comment: I saw the 50% optimal greedy solution in [the Stanford Coursera free online course](https://www.coursera.org/course/algo2). [Here](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/CoursePage.php?course=IntroToAlgorithms)'s video's presented by the same lecturer (see `19. APPROXIMATION ALGORITHMS`). [Here](https://www.cs.uku.fi/~kilpelai/ASA/greedyKnapsack_0.5_approx.pdf) seems to be an article on the same.

Comment: Since 0/1 knapsack is NP-hard, any *polynomial-time* greedy algorithm for the problem would prove that P = NP. Therefore, any greedy algorithm would have to run in pseudopolynomial or exponential time.

Answer (score 8):

There are no greedy algorithms for 0-1 Knapsack even though greedy works for Fractional Knapsack.

This is because in 0-1 Knapsack you either take **ALL** of the item or you don't take the item at all, unlike in Fractional Knapsack where you can just take part of an item if your bag overflows. This is crucial.

Here is an example that disproves that Greedy Algorithm works for 0-1 Knapsack. Let's say that you have a bag of size 6 and these items:

Item   Value   Size   Value/Size 
A       5.5       4         1.38 
B       4          3         1.33 
C       4          3         1.33

For 0-1 Knapsack, if you tried to be greedy you would always take the item that has the highest Value/Size, which is Item A. After taking Item A, you only have room for an item of size 2 or less so you wouldn't be able to pick up anything else. That means that the only thing you have in your bag is Item A which is a total value of 22.

On the other hand, if you had not been greedy and taken the most valuable item and had instead taken Item B, then you would have enough room to take Item C as well. This would have resulted in a total value of 24 in the bag, which is better than the greedy route.